# Iterated Twin Prime conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers

"**Conjecture**. The sum of a twin prime pair greater than or equal to 24 can be expressed as the sum of two twin prime pairs."

Examples:

```
24 = 12 + 12
36 = 12 + 24
60 = 24 + 36
84 = 24 + 60
120 = 36 + 84 = 60 + 60
144 = 24 + 120 = 60 + 84
204 = 60 + 144 = 84 + 120
...
```

to be more precise:

```
(11+13) = 24 = 12 + 12 = (5+7) + (5+7)
(17+19) = 36 = 12 + 24 = (5+7) + (11+13)
(29+31) = 60 = 24 + 36 = (11+13) + (17+19)
(41+43) = 84 = 24 + 60 = (11+13) + (29+31)
(59+61) = 120 = 36 + 84 = (17+19) + (41+43) = 60 + 60 = (29+31) + (29+31)
...
```

Is it always true or are there counterexamples? Is it a known conjecture?

There are no exceptions it works for all sum of twin prime pairs less than 19.999.944.

For example, for (197,199)

15-th 396

```
396=12+384
396=36+360
396=120+276
```

Further details can be found in our post: https://bhaxor.blog.hu/2019/03/03/batf41_haxor_stream_conjecture

I would like to know whether is it a known observation? Is it true for all sum of twin prime pairs greater than or equal to 24? I am curious for your opinion.

(When I was trying to check these I found the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544221/twin-primes-sums-conjecture that contains a similar conjecture. My question originally was posted as a comment to this.)

Comment: Given that the twin prime conjecture is open, and overall we know next to nothing about twin primes,, do you really expect the answer to be known

Comment: This is a cross-post of a Math.SE question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134627/bátf41-haxor-stream-conjecture-the-sum-of-a-twin-prime-pair) that you asked yesterday.  We usually recommend against cross-posting, since one may end up with unnecessary duplication of effort.

Comment: You were very lucky to stumble across your own post from yesterday. Oh, and naming a conjecture after yourself is bound to create a very bad impression.

Comment: @GerryMyerson FWIW I think the OP meant to link to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544221/twin-primes-sums-conjecture

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks,  I have corrected the bad link in the question.

Comment: @YemonChoi yes, thanks, as it can be seen in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134627/bátf41-haxor-stream-conjecture-the-sum-of-a-twin-prime-pair too.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The Batf41 Haxor Stream is the name of our programming and gaming Twitch channel where we (with my children) have presented my observation, https://www.twitch.tv/videos/389883172

Comment: I have no idea what a "Twitch channel" is, but whatever it may be, you have named yours after yourself, which means you have named the conjecture after yourself, which etc. etc. Why not call it the Iterated Twin Prime conjecture?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the name suggestion. I think it is a great name  because it emphasizes the nature of the conjecture. I am going to change the title.

Comment: If $m > 4204$ and is of the form $6k-2$, then it appears that $m=p+q$ with $p,p+2,q,q+2$ prime. That such a thing is true should follow from the usual conjectures. It's harder than twin primes so don't expect it to be proved. If $r,r+2$ are twin primes then the above applies to $m=r-1$ and gives what you want, namely $m=p+q$ so $2r+2 = 2p+2+2q+2$.